# Find the ordinary generating function of given sequence

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, generating-functions

Given a seqence $(a_0,a_1,a_2\dots,a_n,\dots)$ where $a_n = \binom{n}{2}$,so I can get the the following form:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i}{2}x^i
\\
=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} *i * (i - 1) * x^i
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+2)*(i+1)*x^{i+2}
\\
=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+2)*(i+1)*x^{i}
$$
The latter term can be obtained by taking the second derivative with respect to $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ or $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}x^i$

But these two formulas correspond to different closed forms,which are $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and$\frac{x^2}{1-x}$，and they lead to different answer of this question. So I wonder which one is right and why.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can choose either one. Could you explain how do they lead to different answers?

Comment: Suggestion: You should be able to find the first few terms of the series for $1/(1-x)$ and $x^2/(1-x)$ by "long division" of polynomials.  This should enable you to check which (if either) of your solutions is correct.

Comment: @flowing if we choose 1/(1-x),then the result  of second derivative is $2/(1-x)^3$.If we choose $x^2/(1-x)$ the result of second derivative is $2/(1-x)+4x/(1-x)^2+2x^2/(1-x)^3$.The first answer is $x^2/(1-x)^3$ and the second answer is more complicated.

Comment: But isn't $ 2/(1−x)+4x/(1−x)^2+2x^2/(1−x)^3=2/(1-x)^3$ by direct calculation?

Comment: @flowing Oh..,I may have miscalculated earlier.Then I have no question about it.Anyway, thanks for your reply :)